# NEXTJS - How to create a function that has different behavior depending on the type of component it is

Tags: javascript, next.js, app-router

Here's my current function :

```js
export const t = (locale, nsKey) => {
  const dictionary = getDictionary(locale)
  return getNestedValue(dictionary, nsKey)
}
```

^ This function intents are to reproduce i18n feature.. to be able to get text from a key like that :
`t('form.classic.name')`
**But in my function, i've to specify the lang, and I want to get rid of that :**

My idea was to use `typeof window === undefined` to know if i'm in a client component or in a server one
But there's still a main problem :
how i could get the langage...

- In my server's components, i've setup a server-context, that can provide the langage.. cool 
  But i can't use it in a Client Component, or i will get a runtime error
- In my client components, i don't know, i usually use the `usePathname` hooks, but i can't use it out of a component and i can't use it by not specifying the `use client` directive

Any idea to how i can solve my problem ?

> Using App Router :nerd: